# runtime error while using Pvporcupine sdk for Picovoice python

Tags: python, runtime-error

I m using pvporcupine python SDK for picovoice for hot word detection, while using the below code I'm getting runtime error

```
import pvporcupine

access_key = "[my_acces_key]" # AccessKey obtained from Picovoice Console (https://picovoice.ai/console/)
#access key is altered for security reason
handle = pvporcupine.create(access_key=access_key, keywords=['porcupine'])
```

here is the error stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/Pjan/saa2/actions/pic_again.py", line 5, in <module>
    handle = pvporcupine.create(access_key=access_key, keywords=['porcupine'])
File "C:\Users\Pjan\.conda\envs\sam_env\lib\site-packages\pvporcupine\__init__.py", line 82, in create
    sensitivities=sensitivities)
File "C:\Users\Pjan\.conda\envs\sam_env\lib\site-packages\pvporcupine\porcupine.py", line 158, in __init__
    raise self._PICOVOICE_STATUS_TO_EXCEPTION[status]()
pvporcupine.porcupine.PorcupineRuntimeError
```

here is the official site for [picovoice SDK for python](https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine#python)

any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I contacted the official repository of picovoice and here  I mentioned them what clearly was going on.
So anyone still facing it , then here is the solution for such behaviour https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine/issues/617
Thanks!